# Text ellipsis applied to jQPLOT AXIS TICKS

Tags: jqplot

My jqplot graphs have, sometimes, long texts as tick text.

I'd like to ask if is any way to short that text (using jqplot) and to add a tool tip with full text on the tick label?

Comment: @zeltar Have you found any solution for this requirement? I need to do the exact but no concrete solutions provided anywhere.

Comment: @Babu: nope, i didn't find something inside jqplot library. I just built a function to pre-process the tick text: regarding the number of ticks, the function cuts the text to a maximum length and and 3 periods. (...)

Comment: yeah, I did the same and posted my answer here.

Answer (score 0):

**I hope this will help someone looking for the same solution, Originally answered by me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22505258/1309818).**

The hover is not detecting because of the z-index of the canvas which lies on top of the whole chart. I did the following and now it's shorten the tootip by CSS ellipsis and show the tooltip with full name on hover.

Based on the [Gyandeep's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21716054/1309818), the exact JS and CSS I used are,

**Javascript:**

```
$('div.jqplot-xaxis-tick').each(function (i, obj) {
    $(this).prop('title', ($(this).text()));
    $(this).css('z-index', 999);  // this is important otherwise mouseover won't trigger.
});
```

**CSS:**

```
.jqplot-xaxis .jqplot-xaxis-tick {
    position: absolute;
    white-space: pre;
    max-width: 92px;  // Change it according to your need
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

The JavaScript part needs to be executed after every rendering of chart. It's better to put them right after plotting the chart and may in the AJAX success handler.